# как перейти на GNU parallel?

Tags: php, bash, cron

как вот это (это команда запускается кроном 1 раз в минуту)

```
for n in {1..58};
    do php /var/www/upping/data/www/upping.biz/cron/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1 & done
```

переделать под parallel?

Comment: А зачем здесь parallel? что бы быстрее работало?

Comment: да..скрипт тяжёлый и задач много

Comment: а может просто для начала убрать `sleep 1;`? а там и быстрее заработает.

Comment: так он не успевает и 4 раз сделать, т.к. ждёт выполнения первого раза (а он может и под пол минуты работать)...скрипт тяжелый..

Comment: уберите sleep и в конец команды добавьте & (а вот точка с запятой там похоже не нужна) и все команды будут запускаться именно в параллель (насколько это позволит операционная система).

Comment: так?

for n in {1..58};   
    do php /var/www/upping/data/www/upping.biz/cron/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    done

получил
/root/cron.php.sh: 2: /root/cron.php.sh: Syntax error: "done" unexpected
/root/cron.php.sh: 1: /root/cron.php.sh: dev/null: not found

Comment: я визуально пока проблем не вижу, но лучше обновите вопрос с правильным новым скриптом. У меня в консоли вот так `for i in {1..100}; do php -i  >/dev/null  2>&1 & done` работает как ожидается.

Comment: всё равно 1 раз запускается..

Comment: проверьте с помощью pgrep php или чего то подобного, сколько по факту запускается.
Но может быть внутри скрипта есть глобальный мютекс

Comment: там в скрипте письмо сразу отсылается по факту запуска..так вот письма 1 раз в минуту приходят

Comment: значит, помимо отправки сообщения, там присутствует ещё и проверка на наличие уже запущенного процесса.

Comment: почему то {1..58} не отрабатывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parallel -N0 php /var/www/upping/data/www/upping.biz/cron/cron.php ::: {1..58} >/dev/null 2>&1
```